# Coding a Traffic light post

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in need of some help to code a traffic light post for my schoolwork. I have the actual lights all working but I'm not allowed to post the code online. We are working with JavaScript, html and CSS and I am looking for some code which produces a grey, rounded post to put underneath. If this isn't possible then a rectangular post would also be okay. Also looking for tips on how to design a green arrow like the ones in the image. Thanks :)
[Green traffic light arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyVj2.png)

Comment: You can share the code inside the snippet.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
      ctx.lineTo(450, 55000);
      ctx.stroke();

Comment: This literally all I have managed so far, yes its just a line but I figured with width adjustments and positioning it would do as a post..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These elements should get you started.

```css
.pole{
  position: relative;}

.rounded-post {
  width: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #000;
}
.red-light {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: animate-red 3s linear 2s infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animate-red 3s linear 2s infinite alternate;
  animation: animate-red 3s linear 2s infinite alternate;
}
/*Animation Red*/

@-webkit-keyframes animate-red {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    background: yellow;
  }
  100% {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pole">
<div class="rounded-post"></div>
<div class="red-light"></div>
  </div>
```

For the Arrow you can use http://fontawesome.io/ icons ( you can color them however you want)

The idea is to use position: relative and absolute to position your elements. Also you can use css animations to make the lights ON/OFF